# Function accepts format myFunc(x = c(obj[[1]], obj[[2]], obj[[3]])), but doesn't accept myFunc(x = obj) or myFunc(x = unlist(obj))

Tags: r, list, bioconductor, iranges

I am trying to combine several grange objects in R using the [reduce](https://stuartlab.org/signac/reference/inter-range-methods.html)() function. I already have the grange objects stored in a list, but I can't figure out how to pass the list onto the reduce function.

I have tried

```
reduce(x = granges))
reduce(x = unlist(granges))
reduce(x = c(unlist(granges)))
```

but all of these output:

*Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
unable to find an inherited method for function 'reduce' for signature '"list"'*

So it seems the object still remains a list. So far only

```
reduce(x = c(granges[[1]],granges[[2]],granges[[3]])))
```

works. I suspect that there should be a simpler way that I'm just unfamiliar with.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the output for `class(c(granges[[1]], granges[[2]], granges[[3]]))`?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: ```> class(c(granges[[1]], granges[[2]], granges[[3]]))
[1] "GRanges"
attr(,"package")
[1] "GenomicRanges"
Warning message:
In .Seqinfo.mergexy(x, y) :
  Each of the 2 combined objects has sequence levels not in the other:
  - in 'x': scaffold228, scaffold450
  - in 'y': scaffold137, scaffold242, scaffold53
  Make sure to always combine/compare objects based on the same reference
  genome (use suppressWarnings() to suppress this warning).```

Comment: @rdv Try `lapply(granges, reduce)`

Comment: `lapply` produces a new list, and `reduce` ran on the individual grange objects without combining them. What I am supposed to get is a new object with the original grange objects condensed into a single object.